# How can I use lottie animation in GestureHandler React-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

Today I want to use lottie animation  in GestureHandler from **react-native reanimated** as  I said above. But something went wrong. When i call `lottie.current.play(0, 15);` for exemple code -

```
const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (_) => {
lottie.current.play(0, 15);    
},
    onActive: () => {
    },
    onEnd: (_) => {
    },
  });
```

I got error

> ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
> 'lottie.current.play')

I can't understand why?

I have made a reference to the object

```
  const lottie = useRef();
 .
 .
 .
       <Lottie
            source={require("./assets/cart.json")}
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100, alignSelf: "center" }}
            autoPlay={false}
            loop={false}
            ref={lottie}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
```

Also found that I can use `lottie.current.play(0, 15);`  the function in **React.useEffect** but why i cant use in in this events `onStart, onActive, onEnd`

Answer (score 0):

> Basically onStart, onActive and onEnd are full-fledged worklets, i.e.
> javascript functions that will be executed on the UI Thread.
> Consequently if you have functions that can only be executed on the
> javascript thread and need to be launched from a worklet it must
> always be specified with runOnJS.

So i should -

```
  const playAnim = (num) => {
    lottie.current.play(num);
  }; 
  runOnJS(playAnim)(15);
```